# Why is the font size on the pdf version of a webpage smaller than the font size on the webpage itself?

Tags: html, css, pdf, web, font-size

If we were to visit the lorem ipsum site https://www.lipsum.com/ on windows 10 chrome and use chrome's Microsoft Print to PDF feature, the font size in the pdf and webpage are different. Attached image as example:
[image]
On the left is the PDF version of the webpage viewed through Adobe Acrobat Reader DC at a zoom level of 100% and on the right is the actual webpage itself. Why does this happen and how do I make the font size in the PDF identical to it's web counterpart?

Comment: In Adobe Page Display Preferences there is an entire Resolution section. Most likely you want that set to 96, to match what your browser DPI probably is. Or at least you would want to determine what your browser DPI is, and then match that in Adobe, or vice-versa.